# UTF-8 and PHP, mbstring.func_overload doesn't work 

Tags: php, character-encoding, multibyte

I have:

```
ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
ini_set('mbstring.func_overload',7);

echo strlen("õôóõêç");
```

The strlen prints 12, instead of 6.

Any suggestion?
http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: what is the OS of the server? windows doesnt work like unix in multibinary process translation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`mbstring.func_overload`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php) [can only be set from php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) (or httpd.conf), and not at runtime.

Comment: @yes123: Feature request over at bugs.php.net? Although I wouldn't hold my breath.